# FTP command keeps running on command prompt. It uses a dat file as input

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

BAT file Code is as below:

```
set SCRIPT_NAME=FTP_SCRIPT.DAT
@echo open "Server"> %SCRIPT_NAME%
@echo "User">> %SCRIPT_NAME%
@echo "Password">> %SCRIPT_NAME%
@echo bin>> %SCRIPT_NAME%
@echo hash>> %SCRIPT_NAME%

@echo mput export.csv>> %SCRIPT_NAME%
@echo y>> %SCRIPT_NAME%
@echo quit>> %SCRIPT_NAME%

@ftp -n -s:%SCRIPT_NAME%
```

It creates `FTP_SCRIPT.DAT` file correctly, however command prompt remains blank and `FTP` does not occur at all. I am using batch scripting for first time. So do not know much details of it. How will this `FTP` command work?

Comment: Take the `@` off the `ftp` command to see what error it gives, using the `@` will suppress valuable debugging messages! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error in your script, but make sure you put the correct ftp direction at open command: "xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.:PortNum"

Try this:

```
SET "SCRIPT_NAME=FTP_SCRIPT.DAT"

(

 ECHO open "Server:Port"
 ECHO "User"
 ECHO "Password"
 ECHO bin
 ECHO hash
 ECHO mput "export.csv"
 ECHO y
 ECHO close

)>"%SCRIPT_NAME%"

%WINDIR%\system32\FTP.exe -n -s:"%SCRIPT_NAME%"
```

Comment: this script also keeps running in command prompt and I have to close it. It creates the dat file but after FTP command it keep running. Please help.

Comment: I've edited my answer, just use "close" command to return to CMD instead of "quit" that only exists from ftp server, you can try the command "bye" too.

Comment: I kept this file in system32 folder of windows and it worked. But how is it possible to keep the script on desktop and still make it work.

Comment: cd C:\WINDOWS\system32
    SET "SCRIPT_NAME=FTP_SCRIPT.dat"

    (

    ECHO open "Server"
    ECHO "User"
    ECHO "Password"
    ECHO bin
    ECHO hash
    ECHO cd "Remote directory"
    ECHO mput "filename"
    ECHO y
    ECHO closed
    ECHO bye

    ) >"%SCRIPT_NAME%"
    ftp -s:%SCRIPT_NAME%>>ank.log
    del %SCRIPT_NAME%

Comment: yes, use the absolute path like in your last comment. you have a problem with your enviroment PATH variable. I've updated my answer please don't forget to accept my answer if helped you, see the rules.